# React SPA. API for global state store for handling login state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

So I have this React component at the root of my website that is login and the page let's call it A. If login is successful it sets the login state to true then switches to another page and then down that tree of those pages(So let's say I have A then B is A's child and C is B's child). Let's say at C I make a rest call to the backend and get back 401 (For whatever reason they're not allowed or their token expired), then I know that the person should not be logged in so it should automatically set the login state at A to false.
I was wondering if there was a way to do this with a global state manager? Something I guess similar to Redux but Redux requires you to pass the store down the component tree as well which I feel is a bit cumbersome and harder to organize well. It'd be nice if I could have a global state store that I can just import.

Comment: if the state in A determines how to render B and C then it makes sense to pass the handler down right? Is that problematic?

Comment: just seems a bit cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

This is the scenario where you should be using stores to maintain the authentication state across your app. You can simply inject it into any component and update the values, and have it referenced by any other component that needs to check.

If you aren't at the point of learning stores quite yet, the way you do this is to store state in the parent component:

```
this.state = {
    authorised: false,
}
```

then add a function to update this:

```
setAuthorisation(value){
    this.setState({authorised: value})
}
```

Now all you have to do is pass both these down to your child components and they can be updated and referenced at any time

```
<Child authCallback={this.setAuthorisation} isAuthorised={this.state.authorised} />
```

You should really be researching this on your own, as it is one of the basics of react :)